# How can get result from OleDbDataReader with C# method

Tags: c#, methods, expandoobject, oledbdatareader

**How can return this from method ????**

**this is important for me**

**thank**

this is my method :

```
public static dynamic GetFactorProperties(int factornumber)
        {
            using (var db = new OleDbConnection(cs))
            {
                db.Open();
                var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM FactorList WHERE FactorNumber = @0", db);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", factornumber);
                var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if(result.Read())
                {
                    return result ;
                }
                else
                {
                    return ProperiesObject();
                }
            }
        }
```

and this is my ExpandoObject()

```
         public static dynamic ProperiesObject()
         {
             dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
            obj.FactorDate = string.Empty;
             obj.FactorNumber = string.Empty;
             obj.CustomerName = string.Empty;
             obj.FactorPrice = string.Empty;
             obj.Discount = string.Empty;
             return obj;
         }
```

and this is read from method source :

```
        var result = Program.GetFactorProperties(factornumber);
        TXTDate.Text = result.FactorDate;
        TXTFactorNumber.Text = result.FactorNumber;
        TXTCustomerName.Text = result.CustomerName;
        TXTFactorParice.Text = result.FactorPrice;
        TXTDiscount.Text = result.Discount;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method should look like this:

```
public static dynamic GetFactorProperties(int factornumber)
{
    using (var db = new OleDbConnection(cs))
    {
         db.Open();
         var cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM FactorList WHERE FactorNumber = @0", db);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@0", factornumber);
         var result = cmd.ExecuteReader();
         if(result.Read())
         {
              dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
              obj.FactorDate = result.GetString(0);
              obj.FactorNumber = result.GetString(1);
              // ...
              return obj;
         }
         else
         {
              return ProperiesObject();
         }
    }
}
```

GetString accepts number of column, from which you want to get value

Comment: thanks for answer , i use your code and seen this error :

Additional information: Specified cast is not valid.

Comment: I don't see your schema. So if data type of your columns not string, u need to u use use methods, ex. GetInt()

Comment: yes my table field is string , but i seen that error , how ever thanks for answering